# Webview certificate pinning

Tags: android, webview

I am implementing a WebView in Android which loads an https website. On this website I want to do certificate pinning which means I want to check certain aspects of the certificate the server serves. However I see there is no method in the WebViewClient that gives me the possibility to intercept the request and also retrieve the certificate.

On the Internet there are a lot of ppl that say that it just can't be done, certificate pinning on Androids WebView. So I hope anyone here knows some more.

Comment: Just refer once : http://stackoverflow.com/a/15590041/4596556 and http://www.mobilephonedevelopment.com/archives/1762 can be useful.

Comment: Yes I have seen this post. However, this about pinning a CLIENT certificate. Plus the rest of these options aren't feasbile.

Comment: Hello, did you find a solution?

Comment: We decided not to go ahead with this whole project because its basically just too insecure.

Answer (score 25):

## Certificate Pinning in Android

Certificate Pinning on Android is described well in [this](https://medium.com/@appmattus/android-security-ssl-pinning-1db8acb6621e) article.

The main milestone in Android for certificate pinning is Android 7.0 Nougat (SDK 24) because of [Network Security Configuration](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config) allowing apps to define their own set of rules.

I suggest the use of [TrustKit Android library](https://github.com/datatheorem/TrustKit-Android) to manage Certificate pinning on Android: it support most libraries (OkHttp etc.) and is compatible with the Android SDK 24 setup.

## Webview Certificate Pinning

However keep in mind that **before Android 7.0** you can't really manage pinning on a Webview, regardless of the library you use, anything that follow is a workaround.

If you have minSDK 7.0 just use the library above, no need to do anything else.

### shouldInterceptRequest workaround

Pre-Nougat the best option you have for Webviews is to implement your own `WebviewClient` and perform the call manually, doing certificate pinning in the `shouldInterceptRequest()` method.

You can find an example of this in [this project](https://github.com/menjoo/Android-SSL-Pinning-WebViews).

The `shouldInterceptRequest()` pre Lollipop (5.0 - SDK 21) do not give you anything more then the URL, no headers, no body, nothing else. This means you can't really do much more then just loading the URL and hope the webapp didn't need anything else (headers etc..).

Since Lollipop you have another method that gives you a `WebResourceRequest` object with more information and so you can reproduce a request properly.

#### Only GET Requests

Regardless of the Android version `shouldInterceptRequest()` will never receive [anything but GET requests](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36918490); **POST/PUT/DELETE are not interceptable**!!

#### Performance Issue pre-Lollipop

Furthermore if you use the method above with `shouldInterceptRequest()` you may introduce [major performance issues](https://artemzin.com/blog/android-webview-io/): [before October 2015](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=533082) the Android Webview had a bug and used to execute the method always on the same Thread causing a blocking queue: the same thread was used for javascript, resulting in apparent ["freeze" of the webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30180529/webviewclient-shouldinterceptrequest-freezes-the-webview). The Webview is upgraded with the system since Lollipop but before that the issue is still present.

#### Workaround of the Workaround for intercepting PUT/POST/DELETE

You can inject a custom Javascript interface for intercepting Ajax calls and  perform them manually with OkHttp or whatever library you use for HTTP request and certificate pinning.

If you really want to go this route [have a look at this library](https://github.com/KonstantinSchubert/request_data_webviewclient), it doesn't support forms, only Ajax call but it can be done in a similar way, like shown in [this other library](https://github.com/KeejOow/android-post-webview).

BUT!!! I wouldn't recommend this AT ALL!!!! The author himself, and I quote, say:

> [..]I wasn't happy with my adaption of this so far.[...]

Cause it's an UGLY HACK!

#### Workaround for the workaround for performance issue

You may consider pre-fetching resources so that you don't have to fetch them when they are requested in the `shouldInterceptRequest()` method. This requires you already know all the resources you'll need and I don't have to tell you that it may end up using a lot of bandwidth and disk space that might never be used by the user.

### Alternatives to `shouldInterceptRequest()`

If you have control over the server providing the Webview data you may try to rely on [**HPKP**](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/09/HPKP-reporting-with-chrome-46), which basically means that your server is supposed to return with each request an header listing SHA256 digest of your certificates: the browser (in this case the webview) is then supposed to pick it up and make sure the next requests will only go through if you the certificate is the same.

Of course this means the first time you have no protection, so you may need a combination of `shouldInterceptRequest()` and HPKP.

It is also really easy to shut yourself in the foot if you do some mistake while setting HPKP up (like explained in the link I gave).

And, guess what, Google, who first introduced HPKP [deprecated it in 2017](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!msg/blink-dev/he9tr7p3rZ8/eNMwKPmUBAAJ) because of the setup difficulties and risk involved in mistakes. This also mean it may not be supported in recent Webviews or in the future.

## Final Remarks

If you really want to securely pin certificate avoid webviews or target minSDK 24 (Android 7.0).

Also consider this...

### Drawbacks

These Drawbacks are generic on the certificate pinning and have nothing to do with the Android version.

Proxies: forget your app working through those if you do certificate pinning. Usually, the only way to make an HTTPS connection work through a proxy is to install your proxy certificate on your device and make the proxy the "Man in the middle". If you pin certificate that won't work, no matter what.

Redirects: if you pin certificate and you have HTTP redirects (301 / 302) that change domain you also need to pin the other domain.

Dynamic content: if your app manage dynamic content (URLs input provided by the user or not under your control) **and** you don't allow anything outside your list of pinned domain/certificates those URLs won't be accepted and you won't be able to pin them anyway because you can't predict which domain / certificate they'll have (this is also true for redirects).

### Do you really need certificate pinning?

There's no pinning for the web, computer browser around the world use no certificate pinning. HPKP (discussed above) has been deprecated by Google itself and no one complained about it so far. Every browser use a list of trusted certificate authorities.

The same things is done by a mobile Device.

The main difference between a browser and a mobile app is that the browser will clearly show certificate information and if the web page is secure or not; while an application can do whatever it wants without showing anything to the user. You could compare a PC application to an App instead to get a more fair comparison.

You need to understand what really pinning the certificate does for the security of your app: it render Man-In-The-Middle attacks impossible to pull off. Even compromised device (user/attacker installed malicious certificate authority) will not allow the communication to establish and thus someone to sniff what your app is sending and receiving.

In order for an attacker to successfully perform a man-in-the-middle attack on a pinned certificate domain he would have to obtain the actual certificate or being able to produce a valid one (from a trusted certificate authority).

The only time in history a trusted certificate authority has been compromised was [DigiNotar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DigiNotar) in 2011. Aside from cases like this the only way to break that chain of trust is with a compromised device (be it a PC or a mobile phone).

Do you need to protect the user against himself? (aka = installing a fake / malicious certificate authority on his device) and then use your application and let his own data and credential be stolen by a MITM.

Do you need to protect yourself against an user stealing data you send through your secure connection? (api keys, tokens, etc...) -- keep in mind there are better tactics to handle this and usually api keys and tokens can be revoked.

Chances are you just need to secure a few API used by your app. [OWASP suggest](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Pinning_Cheat_Sheet), of course to always pin, but I'm more of the idea that you should measure the protection over the threat that this gives you. *This is entirely my opinion.*

OWASP also say another important thing DO NOT DO IT MANUALLY, **you may create greater security threats then the ones you are trying to solve!** (which goes against all the workaround discussed above). And I 100% agree with this one. Use TrustKit.

Comment: You should be careful saying things like, "the only time in history".  Here are a few other prominent incidents of CAs failing or acting badly:  
https://thehackernews.com/2017/07/chrome-certificate-authority.html
https://venturebeat.com/2015/04/02/google-and-mozilla-decide-to-ban-chinese-certificate-authority-cnnic-from-chrome-and-firefox/
https://www.extremetech.com/internet/243202-symantec-caught-improperly-issuing-illegitimate-https-certificates
https://www.cnet.com/news/google-yahoo-skype-targeted-in-attack-linked-to-iran/

Comment: That's all you have to say on my answer? Ok. None of those 2 case you cite are compromised CAs. One is bad behavior and the other involve control of a network. My statement is correct as of today.

Comment: First, I cited 4 cases, not 2: WoSign, CNNIC, Symmantec, Comodo. (those were just the closest ones at hand, there are more).  Second, whether or not your definition of "compromised" excludes bad behavior is irrelevant. If a bad actor gets control of a CA-signed cert due to hacking, theft, mistakes, bad policy, coercion, or other means, the threat is the same, and should be taken into account when designing a security strategy.

Comment: But yes, that's all I wanted to say.  For the rest, I agree that there is some burden introduced by pinning - how much burden depends on your use case and you do need to weigh the costs and benefits.  There are many use cases where it won't make sense.

Comment: TrustKit seems to have compatibility with lower versions as well, From documentation,

"It provides support for the <pin-set> (for SSL pinning) and <debug-overrides> functionality of the Network Security Configuration to earlier versions of Android, down to API level 17. This allows Apps that support versions of Android earlier than N to implement SSL pinning in a way that is future-proof."

Comment: This is a good list. It seems like this version of shouldInterceptRequest added in API 21 does get POST requests as well as GET (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient#shouldInterceptRequest(android.webkit.WebView,%20android.webkit.WebResourceRequest))

Answer (score 3):

On API level 24 (Android 7) and above, you can use [network security config](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config) to pin certificates on application process level, including also WebViews.

Example from the link above. Add to `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<manifest ... >
    <application android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
                    ... >
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Create a resource file `xml/network_security_config.xml`:

```
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config>
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">example.com</domain>
        <pin-set expiration="2018-01-01">
            <pin digest="SHA-256">7HIpactkIAq2Y49orFOOQKurWxmmSFZhBCoQYcRhJ3Y=</pin>
            <!-- backup pin -->
            <pin digest="SHA-256">fwza0LRMXouZHRC8Ei+4PyuldPDcf3UKgO/04cDM1oE=</pin>
        </pin-set>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

Comment: Can you please provide a working example? Also if there are any re-directs can we whitelist the domains?